# Django Model.objects.all() returning empty QuerySet in celery task

Tags: django, docker-compose, celery, django-orm

project/project/settings.py

```
...

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
  'find-subdomains': {
    'task': 'subdiscovery.tasks.mytask',
    'schedule': 10.0
  }
}
```

project/subdiscovery/tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task

from subdiscovery.models import Domain

@shared_task
def mytask():
    print(Domain.objects.all())

    return 99
```

The celery worker shows an empty QuerySet:

```
celery_worker_1  | [2019-08-12 07:07:44,229: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] <QuerySet []>
celery_worker_1  | [2019-08-12 07:07:44,229: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task subdiscovery.tasks.mytask[60c59024-cd19-4ce9-ae69-782a3a81351b] succeeded in 0.004897953000181587s: 99
```

However, importing the same model works in a python shell:

```
./manage.py shell
>>> from subdiscovery.models import Domain
>>> Domain.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Domain: example1.com>, <Domain: example2.com>, <Domain: example3.com>]>
```

I should mention it's running in a docker stack

EDIT:

Ok, entering the running docker container

```
docker exec -it <web service container id> /bin/sh
```

and running

```
$ celery -A project worker -l info
```

works as expected:

```
[2019-08-13 05:12:28,945: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: subdiscovery.tasks.mytask[7b2760cf-1e7f-41f8-bc13-fa4042eedf33]  
[2019-08-13 05:12:28,957: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] <QuerySet [<Domain: uber.com>, <Domain: example1.com>, <Domain: example2.com>, <Domain: example3.com>]>
```

Here's what the docker-compose.yml looks like

```
version: '3'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        image: app-image
        ports:
            - 80:8000
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        command: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 project.wsgi
    redis:
        image: "redis:alpine"
        ports:
            - 6379:6379
    celery_worker:
        working_dir: /app
        command: sh -c './wait-for web:8000 && ./wait-for redis:6379 -- celery -A project worker -l info'
        image: app-image
        depends_on:
            - web
            - redis
    celery_beat:
        working_dir: /app
        command: sh -c 'celery -A project beat -l info'
        image: app-image
        depends_on:
            - celery_worker
```

Any idea why the worker started with docker-compose doesn't work, but entering the running container and starting a worker does?

Comment: It is not possible that in between `Domain` objects have been added?

Comment: No, the task is run periodically by the beat scheduler, giving the same result every 10 seconds

Comment: Please try by restarting celery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting from reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/cpoedr/different_behavior_when_starting_a_celery_worker/ewqx3mp?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

Your problem here is that your celery worker doesn’t see sqlite database. You need to switch to different DB or make your `./app` volume visible.

```
version: '3'

services:
    ...
    celery_worker:
        working_dir: /app
        command: sh -c './wait-for web:8000 && ./wait-for redis:6379 -- celery -A project worker -l info'
        image: app-image
        volumes: # <-here
            - .:/app
        depends_on:
            - web
            - redis
    ...
```

I suggest switching to more production ready DB like postgres